# Words describing relation to scope

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I remember hearing two words, each describing a relationship to scope, or a containing set. I think they are prefixed with *micro-* and *macro-*, but am not certain (I'll call them 1 and 2).

- 1 describes a type of thing which, by definition, is contained within the definition of 2.
- 2 describes a type of thing which, by definition, contains 1.

For example, a square is a 1 of a rectangle. A rectangle is a 2 of a square. An iPhone is a 1 of a computer, and a laptop is also a 1 of a computer.

I hope that makes enough sense. This is difficult to describe because it is so conceptual in nature.

Comment: do you mean *superclass* and *subclass*?  A subclass derives from a superclass.  An iPhone is a subclass of computer.

Comment: or *subset/superset*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- yeah good.

Comment: @Jim: Someone says [The words subclass and superclass were inspired from subset and superset in mathematics](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2087728), but I think that's more if you take the "programmer's perspective". I've no idea if there might be a less domain-specific pair of terms (we do use *mother/daughter* figuratively sometimes, but it's not very "generic").

Comment: Yeah, that's along the right idea, but those aren't the ones I heard and the ones I'm trying to find! @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Jesse: I assume you're looking for a formal/technical pair, rooted in philosophy or logic rather than the modern contexts as used by mathematicians, information theorists, and software designers. I don't know of anything like that off the top of my head - certainly not based on *macro/micro*. Maybe there's a ***hyper/hypo*** pair that would do you? (*over/under* rather than *big/small*).

Comment: How would I go about researching this type of inquiry? I've spent a considerable amount of time Googling, but it seems too broad/conceptual to find refined results. @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Jesse: In ordinary English we just use a copula - *A Norwegian **is** a human being* (unless you're talking about a [Norwegian Blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Parrot_sketch), in which case it's a dead parrot! :). To make the "subordinate" relationship more explicit, you could say something like *[Edvard Munch](http://www.famousbirthdays.com/people/edvard-munch.html) is a **type, instance, example** of a Norwegian*, but it sounds a bit weird. We just don't normally talk/think like that - especially in the opposite direction *(Norwegian is the **category** that contains Edvard Munch)*.

Comment: I found it on the duplicate page. They are hyponym and hypernym. @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for ***microcosm*** and ***macrocosm***? Both describe sets.

Comment: A square is a microcosm of a rectangle? A computer is a macrocosm of an iPhone? I agree that OP *could* be thinking of these terms, but if he is he's misapprehended their meanings.

Comment: No, not these. But thanks for the effort!